# ATI Proprietary Drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, updates, graphics, 13.04

I've been holding back all xserver-xorg* updates in order to keep from breaking the ATI drivers but apparently I'm not holding back enough because my recent update broke them. I'm using catalyst 13.4 on amd64.

In order to keep from breaking video with the ATI drivers, what packages should I be holding back?

Also, I've seen various methods of installing these drivers (i.e. from the amd website, from a ppa). Is there a preferred method?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I recommend to stick to the packages supplied by the Ubuntu repositories. If you for any reason need to use a different version, I personally recommend to use the driver from the AMD website to build *distribution specific packages* and then to install these packages. By doing that, the AMD drivers will be added to DKMS, what means that they don't need to be reinstalled manually every time the kernel gets updated. Actually I never had to hold back any packages when installing the AMD drivers that way.

Comment: Excellent, I'll definitely give that a try. Thanks.